# How To Get a New Bitcoin Payment Address

Tags: blockchain, network, money, payment

I have one bitcoin ewallet and this has one bitcoin payment address.  I have read we should change our bitcoin payment address frequently for security reasons.  How do we do that?

Comment: It depends ... which wallet are you using ? Like a blockchain wallet ?

Comment: How are you planning to take payments? Do you want a solution aimed at taking payments on the web automatically, or one aimed at retail businesses?

Answer (score 2):

Most online wallets will create for you a new address each time you indicate that you want to receive a transaction, or give the option of creating a new address. Some enforce this by never showing an address twice and simply handle amalgamation  on the backend.

Creating a new address for each transaction is a fool-proof way of ensuring that someone has paid you, because you've given that address to only that person and no one else. There are also some privacy benefits, as using a new address makes it more difficult to trace the bitcoin trail.